# Trying to return a row from MySql using a function inside a route and won't get a response

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

So i'm trying to use a function that returns a row from a mySql database inside my route here:

```
.get('/users', function (req, res){
    res.send(userInfo(req.user.id));
})
```

Here is the function:

```
function userInfo(id){
    colDB.query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, rows){
        if (err)
            return {Error: defErrorMsg};
        else
            return rows;
})}
```

I'm fairly new to node and I can't figure out why isn't this working. Please help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is to do with the callback nature of node. You are returning the value before it exists (treating async code like it's synchronous). Try the following:

```
function userInfo(id, callback){
    colDB.query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?', [id], function(err, rows){
        if (err)
            callback(err, null);
        else
            callback(null, rows);
})}
```

And then change the route to look like this:

```
.get('/users', function (req, res){
    userInfo(req.user.id, function(err, user){
      if(err) return res.send(err)
      res.send(user)
    });
})
```

Comment: Awesome it works!
Is there a way to combine the results of a few .get routes I have that use this function into a single string under a different .get route?

Comment: Glad I could help! Can you expand a little? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: Using callbacks to implement and develop in JS leads to callback hell. Consider upgrading your code to use promises instead.